# Can an SFP+ transceiver be set up without a protocol IC, etc.?

Tags: fiber, fiber-optics

I am looking to use an SFP+ simplex BiDi transceiver in order to replace two 820 nm HFBR Avago modules, one Tx and one Rx. Being an SFP+ module, this seems to require a lot more circuitry to run than the Avagos, which are basically just LEDs.

Can I use the SFP+ transceiver in a similar way to the Avagos? Do I need to power the device, or can I just hook straight up to the transmit and receive pins and nothing else? Is there anything else I should know?

[image: Recommended circuit]

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to power the device

Yes. Pins 1, 10-11, 14-17, 20.

> Is there anything else I should know? Thanks!

You also need to drive the control lines:

- Tx_DISABLE (3) low,
- Tx_FAULT (2) and EEPROM/DETECT (4,5,6) via 10k pull-up to VCC,
- RX_RATE_SELECT (7) per SFP+ spec,
- TX_RATE_SELECT (9) per SFP+ spec.

Comment: What voltage on Pins 1, 10-11, 14-17, and 20? what is SFP+ spec for Tx and Rx rate select?

Comment: AFAIK the specs are free, just need a registration.